# Code to include HTML snipets not working

Tags: javascript, html

I tried including the 'tab.html' and ‘content.html’ into my 'index.html' (using w3school code: how to include HTML, found at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp), but the javascript and css elements do not work. The buttons don't work as intended. Look at:
https://rads-198409.appspot.com

If you resize (to a smaller size) the browser window, the tab is supposed to change to a drop-down menu, but the button does not work at all. I have checked the individual pages and they seem to work just fine, just not when they are combined.

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone help? All the code I used is from w3school and I have only modified the file names (tab.html and content.html to point to the right files). Below are links to the code:

Code for ‘tab.html’ - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Code for ‘content.html’ - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol

Code for ‘index.html’ - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_2

Comment: how about adding **your** code to **your** question rather than links to a bunch of `w3schools` rubbish that means nothing

Comment: READ the question

Comment: I did. And there is no code in it to help with

Comment: console error show myfunction() is undefine. Please use myfunction() script in header https://rads-198409.appspot.com/tab.html

Comment: If you're trying to include w3school code from w3school server then you probably have a cors issue.  Check your browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: `If you minimize the browser window` - you see nothing, as the window is minimized

Comment: if you do click the "drop down" ... you get an **error in the developer tools console** ... `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

Comment: I think you are talking about responsiveness @CodeMonkey. Is it that your buttons are not working in small page size?

Comment: Please provide all code to replicate your issue **in the question itself** . Make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Don't make us go off to third party sites to find your code, or worse assemble it from several sources. We like to see a [MCVE] in the question, and if possible use StackSnippets, the `<>` button in the question editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is why:

1. The links take you nowhere. #home (or # then whatever) is referring to an element in the page. This means that the link doesn't actually take you anywhere, unless you actually change the link to something else.
2. You're using a w3schools template. Come on, man!

Explanation on #1:
Say there was a footer at the bottom of a page, named "footer". To jump to that element, all you have to do is put #footer at the end of the url, and your browser will jump your screen to the bottom. Similarly, the #home hash means that it goes to a place where an element called home is. In this case, that's the top. The other buttons though, refer to different elements. The problem is that these elements don't exist in the template. To make them work, you must change the url to a real working url, or create elements with ids such as "news", "contacts", and such.

Comment: PFFT, I can't even reply to a comment yet, I only have 3 reputation

Comment: No no, I know I’m using a template! I wasn’t concerned about the links not working! My concern is tgat the button does not work when the browser window is minimized.

Comment: Again, your href values for the elements are not working, because the elements you are referring to don't exist.

Comment: You also don't have myFunction() defined, do you?

Comment: Dude! Look at the button to your right when browser window is resized - just reduce the width and see. I am concerned about that, not the links. The button doesn’t work. I know I haven’t included any links.

Comment: I literally have an app running on that template, I know what I'm saying.

Comment: You don't have myFunction() defined. When the button is clicked, it triggers myFunction(), but you never declared what myFunction() was in the first place. You need something like 

function myFunction(){
if(document.getElementById("mobile").style.display!="block"){
document.getElementById("mobile").style.display="block";
}else{document.getElementById("mobile").style.display="none";}
}

Comment: Oh Ok, which file is that in - tab.html or index.html? Where does code go? Sorry I am new to web development...

Comment: index.html, I think.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - have you looked in your **developer** tools console, to see the error `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

Comment: @Jaromanda X same here I'm 14 and even I know how to go into dev console

Comment: You were looking for something like http://output.jsbin.com/tivohug# right?

Comment: I don’t care whether you’re 12 or 13. I just want to know which file is the culprit and what code to define the function, where to insert it.

Comment: function myFunction(){ if(document.getElementById("mobile").style.display!="block"){ document.getElementById("mobile").style.display="block"; }else{document.getElementById("mobile").style.display="none";} }
SOMETHING LIKE THAT

Comment: @Tamil Selvan C -you’re right it’s in tab.html! How and what do I add in the header?